# Summing the odd numbers in a list using list comprehension, for and if in one line

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, sum, list-comprehension

I am learning Python and I am trying out some exercises.  I am trying to sum all the odd numbers from 0 to 9 using list comprehension, for and if in one line.

I tried the following code:

```
for idx in range(10): s = 0 if idx == 0 else s = [(i % 2) for i in range(10)][idx] * range(10)[idx] + s
```

but I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression
```

I don't quite understand it.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can one line it this reduce

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y if y%2 != 0 else x ,range(10))
```

output

> 25

Comment: `functools.reduce` in python 3.

Answer (score 7):

very short oneliner:

```
sum(range(1,10,2))
```

but the real formula is for any `n`:

```
((n+1)//2)**2
```

With that one, you're able compute the sum for a very big `n` very quickly.

Back to the point, you cannot accumulate using a list comprehension, or it's very difficult/hacky to do, so `sum` is required here. So the most logical if requirements are "use a comprehension notation and an if" is:

```
sum(x for x in range(1,10) if x % 2)
```

Note that there's no need to put an extra `[]` in that case. It's a *generator comprehension* (avoids generating an extra `list`, `sum` doesn't need to have all the info at once.

Comment: I've enjoyed watching the progression of solutions becoming more and more succinct.

Comment: Nice one Jean !

Comment: He is trying  out an example to understand list comprehension :D

Comment: yeah, I did the exact opposite, I know. I have added a generator comprehension solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you may do it

```
sum([x for x in range(1,10,2)])
```

**Explaining why your  code failed**

Here is your code as given in the question

```
for idx in range(10):
    s = 0 if idx == 0 else ([(i % 2) for i in range(10)][idx] * range(10)[idx] + s)
```

in the `else` part you may give the value to be assigned to s ie, `s=` is not required.You may re-write it as

```
for idx in range(10):
    s = 0 if idx == 0 else ([(i % 2) for i in range(10)][idx] * range(10)[idx] + s)
```

The expression syntax for ternary operator in python is as follows

```
condition_is_true if condition else condition_is_false
```

Eg usage

```
value1 = 10
value2 = 20
a = 3
b = 4
value = value1 if a > b else value2
print value
#20
```

Comment: `sum([x for x in range(1,10,2)]` is incorrect syntax BTW.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre updated ,missed ')' . Thanks for pointing it

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
sum([x for x in range(10) if x % 2 != 0])
```

First you create a list of number from 0 to 9 with `range`, then you create the list (list comprehension) of the odd numbers (using `if x % 2`). Finally, you sum the contents of the array using `sum`.

Comment: should be range(10)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this ..

```
a = range(0,10)
b = sum([x for x in a if x%2 != 0])
print b
```

output :

```
25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = range(0, 10)

def addOddNumbers(numbers):
    for num in numbers:
        if num % 2 == 1:
            return sum
        print sum(numbers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    addOddNumbers(numbers)
```

Comment: The question ask for a `one line` solution

Comment: hi @bindhu, please add some explanations to your answer. It is not helpful.